# Injecting an ID selector into a style

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

**UPDATE**: Here is [my own fiddle that demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/GyJA5/) - note that the border and colours are picked up, but not the font.

Looking at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emilkaiser/DECrB/), we have this CSS:

```
#mapbox .myinfo {
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

And this Javascript:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: center,
    content: '<div class="myinfo">Computer History!</div>'
});
```

When using the [MarkerWithLabel class](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html), I have (approximately) this code:

```
.myinfo {
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
    font-size:18px;
}

new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: location,
    draggable: false,
    map: this.map,
    labelContent: "99",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
    labelClass: "myinfo",
    title: "Value 99 at location X"
});
```

I cannot use a `#mapbox` in my CSS file, as the map ID can change, and there can even be two maps on a single page. Is there a trick to dynamically add an ID to a style or otherwise work around my problem? Other StackOverflow questions suggested using `!important`, but that completely destroyed the marker layout.

Comment: Where is the fiddle that you mentioned on line 1?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you _need_ to use #mapbox?  [Using your code, the myinfo style is applied to the label on the marker](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_markerwithlabel_basic_class.html)

Comment: @geocodezip: that's weird! However, in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyJA5/), the font isn't being set, even though the colour and border attributes are.

Comment: Are you going to publish your map in a fiddle?  It works for me locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an inheritance rather than finding out a workaround.

**For Instance,**

```
div.gm-style-iw > div > div.myinfo {
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
    font-size:18px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

What this will do is, get your values by inherting the classes from the predefined google map classes and that will be applied automatically by your set class values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't - I [made a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyJA5/), then [forked with your changes](http://jsfiddle.net/Ffwxg/), but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What is the issue that you are still facing? - @KenY-N

Comment: The problem I am still facing is if I look at Chrome's Elements/Style debugging window, I see my own style (`.myinfo` in this example) with the `font-family`, `font-size` and `font-weight` struck out. `text-align`, `width` and `border` are accepted, however. `.gm-style a` seems to be the style that "wins". Looking at @geocodezip's example above, it has none of the `.gm-style` that I see in my own code.

Comment: Doh! I was using `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` which gives me the bleeding edge release, but if I use `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false` I get a superfluous-CSS-free version. [See this question for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281770/disable-css-styles-in-google-maps-3-14-infowindow).